# Get audio blob from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to list the audio blob from database:
and I'm getting this error:

`error: PCDATA invalid Char value 3`

```
while($img_audio = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<audio>
    <?php echo utf8_encode(utf8_decode($img_audio['audio'])); ?>
</audio>
<?php }
```

Comment: your `audio` tag is [wrong](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp). why do you do `utf8_encode(utf8_decode())` ? what is theses : `</audio_historia>` and `<lista>` ?

Comment: <lista> and </audioHistoria> are only tags which I use to consume the web service. I need only know what is wrong with § <audio><?php echo utf8_encode(utf8_decode($img_audio['audio'])); ?>
</audio>

Comment: Use store in BLOB base64encode, and get date from BLOB and base64decode

Comment: If the data is stored in a BLOB, why would it need to be Base 64 encoded?  Surely mysql would deal with the encoding?

Comment: pls, write this as an answer and I mark as correct